# Authenticate ColdFusion Application with Azure for creating contact groups

Tags: azure, coldfusion, azure-active-directory

I am trying to publish contact group into Azure Active Directory.

Steps that I followed:

1. Register Application in Azure and get the Tenant ID and Client ID.
2. Send the CFHTTP Request for token (I need help here)
3. Send token and other parameters (I need help here) to publish the contact groups

   ```
   cfhttp(method="POST", charset="utf-8", url="https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/response_type=code", result="result") {
       cfhttpparam(name="Content-Type", type="header", value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
       cfhttpparam(name="client_id", type="formfield", value="28d5e75-a762-45a2-9504-e9bbaa3294af");
       cfhttpparam(name="grant_type", type="formfield", value="authorization_code");
       cfhttpparam(name="mimetype", type="header", value="application/xml");
   }
   ```

Response:

```
Header  HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found Cache-Control: private Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff x-ms-request-id: caeef2f8-71a0-45f6-8820-63d880f02700 x-ms-ests-server: 2.1.10244.21 - WST ProdSlices P3P: CP="DSP CUR OTPi IND OTRi ONL FIN" Set-Cookie: x-ms-gateway-slice=prod; path=/; SameSite=None; secure; HttpOnly Date: Mon, 23 Mar 2020 18:20:59 GMT Connection: close Content-Length: 0
    Mimetype    Unable to determine MIME type of file.
```

Comment: If you want to get Azure ad access token, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow

Answer (score 0):

1. First step is to Authorize:
   https://login.microsoftonline.com/#tenantID#/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=#clientID#&redirect_uri=#redirectURI#&response_type=code&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default&openid+email+profile+User.Read+User.ReadBasic.All+User.ReadWrite+Directory.Read.All
2. And then get access token using the URL code:

   ```
   cfhttp( method="POST", charset="utf-8", url="https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token", result="auth") {
   cfhttpparam(type="header", name="Content-Type", value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
   cfhttpparam(type="formfield", name="client_id", value="#clientID#");
   cfhttpparam(type="formfield", name="grant_type", value="authorization_code");
   cfhttpparam(type="header", name="mimetype", value="application/xml");}
   ```